# Install Applications like Java,tomcat,etc. and after that build an app using jenkins and then deploy on a remote server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

When i get an empty Ubuntu server like 172.22... I want to install java ,download Apache-tomcat and install. After that build my appliaction and deploy it on the server. I have used [**Publish Over SSH Plugin**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwjl6bbFyLLIAhUHA44KHTX2B-s&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.jenkins-ci.org%2Fdisplay%2FJENKINS%2FPublish%2BOver%2BSSH%2BPlugin&usg=AFQjCNFGJdV-0E5XCiB2vkNRLX2EAvDg7Q&sig2=X8OjNZec18o2gEvOPnETtg&bvm=bv.104615367,d.c2E) to transfer some scripts to run when it on server but the problem is it only takes scripts from the application space where it is build.For that it this initial setup scripts must also be present inside every application i build.

In ideal scenario I want one job to setup a server by installing applications like java , tomcat.. etc. in remote server and then one job to build an application and deploy it on that remote server.Can't we do this using Jenkins ?

Answer (score 0):

Possible sollution of deploy:
On jenkins server install plugin to execute Shell scripts. That allow us to run Curl command. To deploy .war on remote server use command with curl, example:

curl -T /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/(Path to war ) http://user:password@ip:port/manager/text/deploy?path=/(nameOfWar)&update=true

Also add role manager-script to Your tomcat user.

For deploy on linux servers i use plugin Deploy war/ear to a container. So it's all in Jenkins and Tomcat.

In case doing a remote install from one job i preffer to use ssh plugin, even better sollution is to write a perl script put it on server then run it. To run ssh command by perl for example use: $tomcat = `apt get install tomcat`; etc.